# Reinstalling SQL Server where SP Config Database resides

Tags: 2013, sql-server-2012

My SharePoint Farm is a stand-alone farm and
I want to reinstall the SQL Server.

Will SharePoint exist after uninstalling SQL Server? 
Because the config database resides in this SQL Server and I want to re-install the SQL Server on this same machine again. After running SP Config Wizard, will Config DB create in the new SQL Server setup?

I have never done this before and cannot find any relevant information on the web.
Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing for you to do here is treat this as a SQL database migration.  Basically you will either need to create a backup of each SQL database or detach the databases.  Once you have reconfigured SQL, you can restore the backups or reattach the databases.

I would also think about why you are reinstalling SQL. You can upgrade the edition, the version, etc., without removing the current instance.  And you could use the SQL installation repair function to fix broken instances.

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks for the response. The re-installation for current SQL Server instance is required to enable Reporting Service in SharePoint Integrated Mode. My SQL Server instance is a 2012 Enterprise Version and I mistakenly installed the Reporting Service in Native Mode due to which I am unable to perform some operations in SSRS report building.

Comment: You can run the Reporting Services configuration tool (in your start menu) to reconfigure it as SharePoint integrated.

Comment: Hi John, the feature of reconfiguring from Native Mode to SharePoint Integrated Mode has been removed in SQL Server 2012 edition. I have confirmed this from Microsoft.

Comment: I see that now, it still lets you reconfigure the SSRS database, but doesn't do everything required for the switch.  The simplest solution would be to simply install a new instance of SSRS in SharePoint mode. (No need to affect the current instance)

Comment: Yes John, I have already re-installed the SQL Server instance.